# How to incorporate mongodb 3.0 java driver and query builder?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

With mongodb 2.10.0 java driver following code sample worked for me.

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");
DBCollection eventCollection = db.getCollection("event");
DBObject query = new QueryBuilder().start().and(new QueryBuilder().start().put("event_type").is("deploy").get()).get();
DBCursor cursor = eventCollection.find(query);
```

In mongodb 3.0 java driver for `MongoCollection<Document>` it seems `find(query)` is not available.

Is there an alternative method to use query builder with mongo-java-driver 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems QueryBuilder is not available for mongodb java driver 3.0 version and the new approach is based on filters.

```
MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("testdb");

MongoCollection<Document> eventCollection = db.getCollection("event");

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = eventCollection.find(eq("event_type", "deploy")).iterator();
```

And filters must be imported as static.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
```